# FATAL ERROR get_label() woocommerce shipping

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Im having an issue with woocommerce shipping, here's the error im getting on cart page.

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function get_label() on null in public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-cart-functions.php on line 327
```

Screenshot is also attached.
[image]

wc-cart-functions.php

```
function wc_cart_totals_shipping_method_label( $method ) {
    $label = $method->get_label();

    if ( $method->cost > 0 ) {
        if ( WC()->cart->tax_display_cart == 'excl' ) {
            $label .= ': ' . wc_price( $method->cost );
            if ( $method->get_shipping_tax() > 0 && WC()->cart->prices_include_tax ) {
                $label .= ' <small class="tax_label">' . WC()->countries->ex_tax_or_vat() . '</small>';
            }
        } else {
            $label .= ': ' . wc_price( $method->cost + $method->get_shipping_tax() );
            if ( $method->get_shipping_tax() > 0 && ! WC()->cart->prices_include_tax ) {
                $label .= ' <small class="tax_label">' . WC()->countries->inc_tax_or_vat() . '</small>';
            }
        }
    }

    return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_shipping_method_full_label', $label, $method );
}
```

get_label()

```
public function get_label() {
        return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_shipping_rate_label', $this->label );
    }
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: can you copy paste the part of code that is causing the issue? 
maybe like line 320 to line 335

Comment: search woocommerce files and find the body of get_label()

Comment: question updated with get_label() body

Answer (score 0):

Please use `add_filter` instead of `apply_filters` in the `get_label()` function. It will resolve your issue.